# Custom Changes in User Model with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm using Devise for registrations. Devise uses my User model to create new users. However, i want to add some custom values to the user model upon registration. I thought something like a before_create filter on the User model, but i'm not sure that is the best choice.

How would you do it ? (without hidden form fields, i need to customize more than that)

Answer (score 0):

You can add any attribute/field to a Devise authentication table like you do for other table in the database. If its not about validating data, use `after_create`

**Update:**

Like if you want to add extra field full_name comprised of first_name and last_name, you can write

```
after_create :populate_full_name

def populate_full_name
    self.full_name = "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
end
```

Comment: I already have the fields. The thing is how do i explicitly set their values upon registration (hidden form fields is not a choice).

Comment: As i mention in my question, i thought of using filters as well. But i'm not entirely confident in the sense that i would need other models to be created as well (user has inventory on registration). Filters would work i suppose, but isn't doing this on registration better ?